# Loop event listener function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to initiate an object dropping down on the click of a button but instead of dropping down smoothly it  drops down a bit each time the button is clicked. To click the button just click where it says drop, I didn't include the stylesheet so it wont look like a button but it still works. The issue lies in the function `this.update`. I want the block to drop down fully on one click of the button.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let dist = document.getElementById("Dist");
let m = document.getElementById("Mass");
let meter = 1;
let start = document.getElementById("start");

canvas.height = 800;
canvas.width = 900;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(65, 163, 193)";
canvas.style.marginLeft = "500px";
canvas.style.marginTop = "75px";

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

let x = 400;
let y = 200;
let h = 40;
let w = 20;
let xSpeed = 0;
let ySpeed = meter;

function Thing(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed, h, w){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;

    this.draw = function(){
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        c.fillStyle = "black";
        c.fill();
        c.stroke();
        c.closePath();
    };

    this.update = function(){
        start.addEventListener("click", () => { 
            if (this.y + this.h > canvas.height){
                this.y -= this.ySpeed;
            };
            this.y += this.ySpeed;
            this.x += this.xSpeed;
            this.draw();
        });
        this.draw()
    };
};

let obj;

function init(){
    obj = new Thing(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed, h, w,);
    anim();
};

function anim(){
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    obj.update();
};

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Physics Drop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <div id="X/Y title"></div>
        <table>
            <tc>
                <tr>
                    <input id="Mass" placeholder="Mass"> 
                </tr>
            </tc>
            <tc>
                <tr>
                    <input id="Dist" placeholder="Height of drop">
                </tr>
            </tc>
        </table>
        <div id="start">
            <div id="startT">Drop</div>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a gameloop, which is function which is run on every frame.
Typical structure of gameloop is as follows:

```
while(1) {
    update() // update the state of object
    draw()   // redraw the object based on updated state
}
```

I've done few things to fix the code

- Add the event listener on `init()`
- update the `obj.y` in the update method
- create a game loop which calls `obj.update()` every 100ms.
- Initial `obj.ySpeed = 0` so it doesn't start falling. Now you can control the fall just by updating the `obj.ySpeed`, therefore just set `obj.ySpeed` on click event to make the object start falling, and set it to 0 when it reached end of the canvas.

Try the new code here [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eabg1y4m/1/)

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let dist = document.getElementById("Dist");
let m = document.getElementById("Mass");
let meter = 10;
let start = document.getElementById("start");

canvas.height = 800;
canvas.width = 900;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(65, 163, 193)";
canvas.style.marginLeft = "500px";
canvas.style.marginTop = "75px";

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

let x = 400;
let y = 200;
let h = 40;
let w = 20;
let xSpeed = 0;
let ySpeed = meter;

function Thing(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed, h, w){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;    

    this.draw = function(){
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        c.fillStyle = "black";
        c.fill();
        c.stroke();
        c.closePath();
    };

    this.update = function(){

        if (this.y + this.h > canvas.height){
          this.y = canvas.height - this.h;
          this.ySpeed = 0;
        };
        this.y += this.ySpeed;
        this.x += this.xSpeed;

        this.draw()
    };
};

let obj;

function init(){
    obj = new Thing(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed, h, w,);
    anim();
    start.addEventListener('click', () => {
        obj.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    });
    setInterval(() => {
            obj.update();
    }, 100)
};

function anim(){
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    obj.update();
};

init();
```